# extjs layouts, embedding html inside extjs viewport

Tags: javascript, extjs

i am trying to layout the following html inside this extjs viewpoint:

```
Ext.application({
name: 'HelloExt',
launch: function() {
    Ext.create('Ext.container.Viewport', {
        layout: 'fit',
        items: [
            {
                title: 'Hello Ext',
                html : 'Hello! Welcome to Ext JS.'
            }
        ]
    });
}
```

});

the HTML:

```
<div id='logo'></div>
<header class='search'>
    <input type="search">
</header>
<br class="clear" />
<header class='main'>
    <nav class='main'>
        <ul>
            <li>Dashboard</li>
            <li>Claims Handling</li>
            <li>Reports</li>
            <li>Accounts</li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <nav class='menu'>
        <ul>
            <li>Mini Portal</li>
            <li>Authorize Transaction</li>
            <li>Insert Invoice Number</li>
            <li>Add Batch Claims</li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
<section id='container'>
    <div class='head'>
        <header class='sub'>
            <h1>Authorize Transaction</h1>
            <nav class='sub'>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="">Authorize</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Insert Number</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Add Batch Claims</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Change Details</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
                            <section class="table"></section>
                            <div id="forms"></div>
        </header>

    </div>
</section>
```

could anyone please explain how this could be done?

Comment: I you need to put your html into the viewport, why have you set html property to 'Hello! Welcome to Ext JS...'? or are you trying somthing else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could format your html like this : http://pastebin.com/7muECqsQ 
and then just reference it when configuring your viewport

```
Ext.application({name: 'HelloExt',launch: function() {
Ext.create('Ext.container.Viewport', {
    layout: 'fit',
    items: [
        {
            title: 'Hello Ext',
            html : innerHtml //your above html
        }
    ]
});
```

}
});

There are several other ways to do this. 
You could create a Template / XTemplate and apply it to the body of the Viewport also.